# Is there a Perl IMAP module with TLS support?

Tags: perl, imap, ssl

I'm writing a Perl script to connect to an IMAP server that requires TLS over port 143. The server does not support connecting over SSL. Thus far, the Perl IMAP modules I have found support only SSL, not TLS.

Are there any Perl IMAP modules that provide TLS support? Thus far I have looked at:

Net::IMAP
Net::IMAP::Simple
Net::IMAP::Client

Net::IMAP::Client supports SSL but not TLS.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You make a non-ssl socket that is later transformed,  "This is also useful if you want to use IO::Socket::INET alternatives, like IO::Socket::SSL."

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-IMAPClient/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pod#Socket

... when you create your method reference here ...

http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL#METHODS

the example here can be easily tuned

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.24/example/ssl_client.pl

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand enough about this to code what needs to be coded. I'm really looking for a module that provides this functionality built-in. In other words, I'd like to simply initiate an IMAP connection and specify "TLS => 1".

On the other hand, I'd also be happy if you were to lay out in a bit more detail exactly how I could get to having an IMAP module with TLS support, using the above methods.

Comment: Make your network connection with io::socket and then hand that connection off to mail::imapclient. It will not try and make its own connection, but rather use the one use made for it.

This allows you to use whatever mechanism you can muster. This is a good thing since we really don't want the mail::imapclient programers reinventing the wheel and  dealing with networking.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, but TLS != SSL. For TLS to work you'd need to create a plain socket, deal with the IMAP STARTTLS command and then transform it into an SSL socket. Whilst IO::Socket::SSL can "upgrade" sockets like this, the STARTTLS negotiation is a part of the IMAP protocol and hence not "reinventing the wheel" - you're making every user of the IMAP client module reinvent the wheel by having to handle that part of the protocol (including any other bits and pieces, e. g. idle events) that turn up during the process, "manually"!

I guess it might be possible to open a socket, dump anything received and just send "STARTTLS\r\n" down it, then call start_SSL and hope for the best. Of course there's no capability checking there unless you do that manually, for which you'd have to look at the IMAP RFCs.

**Mail::IMAPClient** has TLS handling built in, although I've had issues dealing with multipart messages in cases where I only want to download certain parts - if you're grabbing the whole message anyway this won't matter. For me, though, the search continues!

Comment: And I've figured out the issue with parts. There's a small error in the documentation: to get the id of a part on the body-structure object, use ->id _not_ ->bodyid as documented.

Comment: Mail::IMAPClient is the best mail module for me as well.